# Access a column of a matrix as a vector in Eigen

Tags: c++, eigen

How can I access a single vector from a matrix?

For example: Is there a way to extract a vector using something like `A(i)` for a matrix `Eigen::MatrixXf A(10,10)` that returns an `Eigen::VectorXf A(10)`?

Comment: If you have found the answer please add the answer as an answer below so others can benefit from it :)

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Found in the documentation :/ 
The way to access a single column is `.col(i)`, and similarly for row, its `.row(i)`. Also of interest is `.block<>`.

Comment: Here: https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialBlockOperations.html